# Broken colors in command prompt Win7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

Playing with vim colours in terminal mode on Windows 7 I broke some colours in terminal and don't know how to restore everything by default. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you break them?

Comment: I don't know exactly, changed a lot in terminal and in vim colour scheme, and now trying to restore by default (default option in terminal of cause I've tried). My terminal swap some colours and some become just black. For example if you run this script you will see all colours like on the picture http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files but in my terminal some colours will be black (purple for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wish to restore the default colors of the "terminal" window.

Right click the top bar -> (Defaults *or* Properties) -> Colors.
Click on each color and set them as follows into the Selected Color Values.

[image: Command Prompt Properties window]
The colors (left to right), (Red, Green, Blue):

- Black (0, 0, 0)
- Dark Blue (0, 0, 128)
- Dark Green (0, 128, 0)
- Dark Cyan (0, 128, 128)
- Dark Red (128, 0, 0)
- Dark Magenta (128, 0, 128)
- Dark Yellow (128, 128, 0)
- Light Gray (192, 192, 192)
- Dark Gray (128, 128, 128)
- Blue (0, 0, 255)
- Green (0, 255, 0)
- Cyan (0, 255, 255)
- Red (255, 0, 0)
- Magenta (255, 0, 255)
- Yellow (255, 255, 0)
- White (255, 255, 255)

Afterwards, select each of the Screen Text, Screen Background, ... and select corresponding colors (Screen - Light Gray on Black, Popup - Dark Magenta on Black).

Finally, press OK.

If necessary, repeat for another of Defaults or Properties from the context menu.